# Using Near function on multiple variables at same time?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid, proximity

I am trying to calculate between variables and a Fishnet using the Near Analysis Tool.
I have about 50 variables (Binary (Is there "a" information at this location)) for each XY points (300000) and I am trying to calculate the distance between them and a fishnet. (e.g. What distance is variable "a" to the closest square or points of the fishnet).

What I am currently doing is: Separate each of these variables and then calculate them separately on a specific Fishnet (Variable "a" with Fishnet "a") then merging them together.

Is there a way to do that more efficiently?

Comment: Can you provide a more precise description (tools, parameter values) of what you are currently doing, please?  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.